# How to use weights with Elasticnet regression in python?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, glmnet, elastic-net

I am using Elasticnet from scikit-learn in python, I've also used Glmnet package in R for prototyping. 
I want to use weights in Elasticnet which apparently is not available as an option/argument in  Elasticnet in scikit-learn. However it is available in glmnet/elnet in R.

Has anyone used weights with elasticnet in python? Any insight on how it can be done.

Comment: `glmnet` supports weights for both samples, and for various predictors to increase or decrease the regularization strength on a by-variable basis.  Which are you asking about?

Comment: I was asking about sample, My sample had dates and I wanted to assign lower weight to older data wrt to newer data. I achieved it to some extent by duplicating records for newer dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass weights to [SGDRegressor's fit method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.fit), although it is [suggested](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#regression) for big training samples, n > 10000.

I have not used/tested this myself and I do not know the reasoning behind this suggestion, perhaps would be worth looking into for you.

One possible reason I can think of comes from using [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html)  for implementing logistic regression with elasticnet penalty, as suggested in [Scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html). As discussed [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/scikit-learn-getting-sgdclassifier-to-predict-as-well-as-a-logistic-regression) SGDClassifier may have slower convergence compared to better optimized solvers. I have experienced a similar issue with a multinomial logistic model.